# django "<QuerySet{[ ]}" appearing in list

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have been wrestling with something that I think is a bonehead oversight on my part.  I have a form that feeds an input to a view that queries some SQL tables I have and returns a list back with columns from each table**.

The odd thing that is happening is the my list is appearing with

```
<QuerySet{[ ]}>
```

brackets around each list object.  Can anyone tell me how to avoid this?

Much appreciated.

**I am using this list to combine these tables rather than ForeignKeys because I was having a terrible time getting my SQL databases to populate correctly using SQLAlchemy and Postgres and read that there were known issues with that, so I gave up on that method.

views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, Http404
    from django.views import generic
    from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    from .models import *
    from .forms import QuoteForm, RfqForm

    def bom_result(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RfqForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                bom_list = []

                rfq = {}
                rfq_search = form.cleaned_data['rfq_entered']
                rfq['rfq_num'] = rfq_search
                rfq['bom'] = Quotereq.objects.values('bom_entered').filter(rfq_num__exact=rfq_search)
                rfq['part_num'] = Bom.objects.values('partnum').filter(bom__exact='07-00-000019')
                bom_list.append(rfq)

                context = {'bom_list': bom_list}
                return render(request, 'quote/result.html', context)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("<h1>Something Went Wrong</h1>")
        else:
            form = RfqForm()
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'quote/lookup.html', context)
```

result.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock title %}

{% block sidenav %}
    {% for page in page_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{page.permalink}}">{{page.title}}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock sidenav %}
{% block content %}
{% autoescape off %}
{{ content }}
{% endautoescape %}

{% if bom_list %}
{% for bom in bom_list %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><h1>RFQ Number</h1></th>
        <th><h1>BOM</h1></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>


            <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                <li>{{ bom.rfq_num }}</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                <li>{{ bom.bom }}</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                <li>{{ bom.part_num }}</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No Matching RFQ in Database</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Here is what the table outputs:

[image]

Comment: Well `partnum` results in *multiple* results and in a `QuerySet`, so if you want to show these elements, you need to *iterate* over it in the template, and render the individual elements.

Comment: But not using `ForeignKey`s will only result in *more* trouble in the end.

Comment: It is also very weird that you do not filter on specific values, here you will return all `part_number`s for `Bom`s with `bom='07-00-000019'`, and apparently there are a lot of these.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  Two questions to your questions: 1., when I tried to iterate over them I got an error that said those objects were not subsctriptable, so I gave up on that option.  2. Is your advice to suck it up and figure out the ForeignKeys?

Comment: Also,  you're right I would eventually include another variable search for boms.  I have a fixed value in there for testing.

Comment: But you do not need to subscript them, you iterate with `{% for part in bom.part_num %} {{ part }} {% endfor %}`.

Comment: Thank you Willem.  I'm almost there, but now I still have the object label appearing (i.e. {'partnum': '01-13-001596'} instead of just 01-13-001596).  Do you have any suggestions on why that would be?  I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: ah, yes, you need to extract it, with `{% for part in bom.part_num %} {{ part.partnum }} {% endfor %}`, so add a `.partnum` to the variable that renders the elements.

Comment: Thank you Willem, you have helped me several times.  I you post in an answer I'll mark it is correct so you get the deserved points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at what `part_num` is, we see:

```
rfq['part_num'] = Bom.objects.values('partnum').filter(bom__exact='07-00-000019')
```

This is a `QuerySet`, a `QuerySet` is some sort of query that results in a set of objects. You construct such `QuerySet`s by using the Django ORM (what you do here).

In order to obtain the elements in the `QuerySet`, you can iterate over the elements, and for example individually process these.

In the template we can for example write:

```
<td>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li>{% for part in bom.part_num %} {{ part.part_num }} {% endfor %}</li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

So we iterate over the `QuerySet`, we then each time obtain a dictionary (that was wrapped in the `QuerySet`, and we render the value that corresponds to the `'part_num'` key in the dictionary. Of course we can make it more sophisticated (for example use HTML markup directives, like `{% for part in bom.part_num %} <b>{{ part.part_num }}</b> {% endfor %}` to put it in boldface.

> I am using this list to combine these tables rather than ForeignKeys because I was having a terrible time getting my SQL databases to populate correctly using SQLAlchemy and Postgres and read that there were known issues with that, so I gave up on that method.

I would really advice to use `ForeignKey`s, `ManyToManyField`s, etc. to represent relations between entities. Not only will Django allow you to make more expressive queries, it also will add constraints to the database such that columns that correspond to a `ForeignKey` will always point to the primary key of the table where they point at, etc. In case you for example remove a referred entity, you can define triggers what to do (remove related objects, set the foreign key columnn to `NULL`, etc.). Perhaps following the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/) can provide some required information to proceed.

Of course you are free to design and implement the project in the way you like, but my personal experience is that it will probably in the end result in more trouble.